# Having two graphic cards at the same time

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have a ATI HD5870 graphic card as my main one but I need to use CUDA so I bought a Geforce GT630.

Can I plug them both in my PCI-E slots? I obviously want to use one at a time (I have one monitor so I would unplug and re-plug it to the card I want to use each time). My question is: can I do that? What about the drivers?

Comment: Yes, if you have enough slots. What's the specific problem you're experiencing? What have you tried already?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Can the OS handle two drivers at a time?

Comment: Modern OS's can handle more than one video driver.  Setting which one is actively your "primary" will probably be the trouble you run into (based on what you've said so far).  It also depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Please try some stuff and come back with specific questions about actual problems. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both in the system, and have both active.  My suggestion would be to connect your monitor to the ATI card, and just ignore the Geforce, except to do your computations.  No need to connect/disconnect.

If you really want video out from both, if you have a modern monitor, you could probably use the DVI connection to connect to the ATI, and the VGA connection to the Geforce (assuming that it has VGA out), and then toggle the video source on your monitor, rather than fumbling around behind your system.